# Check if other users are running commands on a PC

Tags: windows-10, cmd.exe, remote

I know you can run commands like tasklist and taskkill etc on remote computers.

My question is, can you find out if someone has ran one of these commands on your computer.
My reason for asking is that I suspect someone has issued a taskkill command onto someone else's computer but I can't find a way of proving this.

Any ideas?

All computers are Windows 10 and on the same network. I have full administrative permissions for all computers.

Comment: Anything in event viewer?

Comment: Maybe this link can give you some idea?


sources: How to detect my application is terminated by TASKKILL in Command Prompt?


https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26666694/how-to-detect-my-application-is-terminated-by-taskkill-in-command-prompt